# Script stopped working. I turned off sumbissions & re-enabled later. now script works again, is it too instensive for google?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I created a script for google that runs on a submit form.
It takes a number that is entered in the form, and looks it up in a sheet.
If it finds a match, it then enters the timestamp to the submission form.

Here it is

```
// this is the name of our script, myFunction can be anything.
// e is a special variable, its the form & answers that has 
// just been submitted by a user.

function myFunction(e) { 


    var sessionDate = e.values[0]; // This gets the timestamp of the submission
    var sessionID = e.values[1]; // This gets the session ID the user entered


    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Gets the spreadsheet where the form is attached to and all sheets are stored
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data Dump"); // Specifies the data dump sheet, which has the IDs and the cell we want to add the timestamp to
    var range = sheet.getRange("B:B"); // Specifies the column that holds the session IDs, in the data dump sheet
    var values = range.getValues(); // Reads the data in the sessions ID column, that we specified earlier

    for(i=0;i<values.length;i++){ // This goes through the session ids one by one, and we can test each one


        if (values[i][0] == sessionID){ // This is the test. If the ID we are currently looking at matches the ID on the form response, then lets do something

            sheet.getRange(i+1, 7).setValue(sessionDate); // This is us doing that something. Using where we found the matching ID, lets write the timestamp in a cell.
            break; // This stops us going through anymore ID's as we have already found the one we are looking for

        }
    }

}
```

This worked fine after repeated testing. It was then set to go live.
With the form shared with quite a few people.

There were a lot of submissions, then the script stopped working. Even when manually testing, I got no specific errors. Just Spreadsheet service error.

So I stopped taking responses on the form, a day or two ago. Today's the first change I've had to look at it, and it all works fine. The script runs in seconds.

The only thing I can think is that the script is too intensive for google with multiple submissions going on, I was thinking specifically the `for` loop might be giving it issues.

Has anyone got any idea's or anything I can try?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe a user submitted an invalid sessionID and the Data Dump sheet has too many rows.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote? After previous feedback on questions. I've made sure I annotated my code, tried to lay it out nicely. (thanks for the edits). Tried to make sure question and explanation was concise. So would appreciate any other feedback to improve question quality in future.

Comment: @Rubén Would invalid session ID matter. As we are only doing stuff IF a match is made. If no match is made, nothing is done. I've submitted responses with non-matching ID's and it still ran. 
I will look into the too many rows  idea. Thank you

Comment: It depends on how responses submissions occurs (number and frequency) and on the number of rows of your sheets, I think.

Comment: I would suspect the downvotes come from the JavaScript forum, a few people there are a bit aggressive when they see posts that are not "pure" coding questions... But I don't have enough reputation to see that kind of information so it is only a suspicion build on experience ;-)

Comment: @Sergeinsas Thanks, I only use that tag to help with formatting. Will have to manually format in future and not include that tag.

Comment: actually, you don't need it to format your post (and you can remove whenever you want). Btw, I upvoted to compensate  (almost ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `sheet.getRange(i+1, 7).setValue(sessionDate);` in the loop, put in `range.offset(i, 7).setValue(sessionDate);`

See here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset-columnoffset

However, you are liable to having the script called simultaneously if more than one form is submitted, so locking the script or saving time or queueing the forms might help.

To use a lock (see: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#tryLock(Integer) )

A much more complicated solution to save time/queue forms:
Try a completely different strategy.
E.g.: Rather than calling the `myFunction(e)` upon form submit trigger, store all `e.values` that arrive to `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty`, and simultaneously create a timed trigger to run `myFunction` in a minute, retrieving all stored `e.values` from `PropertiesService` and then processing them all in a chunk. At the same time, any new `e.Values` would be stored in PropertiesService (see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer) )

I realise that these are not simple solutions. If they are interesting to you I can try to help with a script. I am not an expert, though I would give it a go with these options.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggestion.
I've used offseet before, but programmatically, why is it better than the current line?
I've never used lock or  PropertiesService, but would be really interested to see this solution, and if it helps the script behave. If you have any time at all to spare, I'd appreciate your thoughts and input.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think that offset is faster since it does not create or look for a new range.  
However, in your case I don't think that you are writing to the sheet multiple times in that loop, are you?  I think your intention is for one form value coming into the script only; and then finding this value using the loop.  
Can you tell me, how many values are in B:B ... are they fixed, pretty much?
I will look at writing some script in a while.

Comment: Yes,
Session ID's are unique, and only one value is written on an iteration of the script, then it ends.
In B:B potentially their could be 100's or 1000's of ID's. But when the script stopped working, I cleared out most values.
I can always add this data back in. 
perhaps flattening the B:B array into a 1D array, then trying indexOf() instead might be a little less intensive. But I like the lockscript idea, this means another from submission  won't trigger the script, until current one finishes. Thanks for all the help @DavidTew

Comment: OK - looks like you are away: TBH I would only do a search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=LockService.getScriptLock%28%29%3B and then cadge some ideas from these results.  So I won't pretend to be an expert on lockservice. 
Suggestion:  you make it work sufficiently; and then create an answer yourself here; then select your own response as the best answer.  That will complete this query, save me a lot of time! and give you points!

Answer (score 2):

With Form submissions, you should always use `LockService`.  Because the internet can have a bad connection, or Google's servers could be slow, etc. you should have a try/catch when getting the lock:

```
try {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  var isLockt = lock.tryLock(10000);
catch (err) {
  Utilities.sleep(2000);//Wait 2 seconds
  lock = LockService.getScriptLock();//Try again
  isLockt = lock.tryLock(10000);
};

if (!isLockt) { // Not true
  //Email developer.  There was an error
  //Email user.  There was an error.
  //Keep running code?  Or quit?
  return;
};
```

You don't need to loop through your values.  There is a much faster way.  You are only getting one column of data, so you don't need a 2D array.  Take the 2D array and flatten it to 1D.

```
var values = range.getValues();
values = values.toString().split(",");//Convert 2D to 1D

var indexOfSessionID = values.indexOf(sessionID);//Gets index of first
     //occurrence of the sessionID
```

That gives you the index of the first occurrence of the sessionID in the data.  The data is zero indexed, so the index and the row number are out of sync.  Index zero is the first element in the array.  If the range started in row one, then to get the correct row number, add 1 to the index.  If the range started in row two, add 2.

If there were multiple session ID's, `indexOf()` will only get the first one.  But your `for` loop breaks after getting the session ID, so I'm assuming that, that's okay.

Also, I would change this line:

```
var range = sheet.getRange("B:B");
```

TO:

```
var range = sheet.getRange(1,2,sheet.getLastRow());
```

That starts in row 1, column 2, and gets the number of rows up to the last row.

Answer (score 1):

So after lots of thought and some game changing pointers from @David Tew, I think this is the solution.

```
 // this is the name of our script, myFunction can be anything. e is a special variable, its the form & answers that has just been submitted by a user.
 function myFunction(e) {


     var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();

     lock.waitLock(10000);




     var sessionDate = e.values[0]; // This gets the timestamp of the submission
     var sessionID = e.values[1]; // This gets the session ID the user entered


     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Gets the spreadsheet where the form is attached to and all sheets are stored
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data Dump"); // Specifies the data dump sheet, which has the IDs and the cell we want to add the timestamp to
     var range = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow()); // Specifies the column that holds the session IDs, in the data dump sheet
     var values = range.getValues(); // Reads the data in the sessions ID column, that we specified earlier

     // Edits below
     values = values.toString().split(","); //Convert 2D to 1D

     var indexOfSessionID = values.indexOf(sessionID); //Gets index of first
     //occurrence of the sessionID

     if (indexOfSessionID > 0) {
         sheet.getRange(indexOfSessionID + 1, 7).setValue(sessionDate);
     }


     SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     lock.releaseLock();
 }
```

I'm testing it now with multiple users.
Sandy - thanks for the flat array idea, but it'd already struck me as an idea when commenting to David, but copy and paste code. Yum. Thanks.

While I've posted the answer (I think) to my own question, line by line. 
I think the info David pointed me to has to be best answer as it's forced me to revisit old scripts I've made and change how I use an event driven trigger in future. It's also good to show you're trying to make an effort to solve your own problem and avoid downvotes.

I implore anyone writing a script that has an event driven trigger (such as onEdit, onFormsubmit) AND has multiple users triggering that even to read the link David shared.

[GAS Class Lock](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock)

**EDIT BELOW**

4 Different google users submitted 5 responses each with 2mins 10 seconds of each other and it all worked. Going to do a larger test tomorrow.

Comment: @SandyGood Thanks for the updated response with try/catch.
I'll have to play around with it see if i can incorporate it to my code.